# Vector iterator comparison

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, comparison

I have a problem while comparing the values in two vectors.

Following is the sample code of my program:

```
  template <typename T> bool CompareVectors(std::vector<T> vector1, std::vector<T> vector2)
  {
    std::sort(vector1.begin(),vector1.end());
    std::sort(vector2.begin(),vector2.end());
    if (vector1.size() != vector2.size())
      return false;
    else
    {
      bool found = false;
      std::vector<T>::iterator it;
      std::vector<T>::iterator it2;
      for (it = vector1.begin();it != vector1.end(); it++)
      {      
        for(it2 = vector2.begin(); it2 != vector2.end(); it2++)
        {
          if(it == it2) // here i have to check the values in the itearators are equal.
          {
            found = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if(!found)
          return false;
        else
          found = false;
      }
      return true;  
    }
    };
```

In this sample code I have to compare the two vectors. For that I have sorted the two vectors using `std::sort()`. Since the data type in the vector is a template (I am using a class object in the vector), the `std::sort()` is not working properly. Ie, sometimes the two vectors give different order of elements after sorting.

So I am not able to use the `std::equal()` function also.

For an alternative solution, I have used two iterators for the twi vectors.

And iterating one vector and searches that element in the other vector. For this the iterator comparison is cannot be usable.

Comment: How did you implement `operator<` for the sorting ? It is probably your problem ... My bet is you have a vector of pointers and that your items get sorted by their address instead of their values.

Comment: Have you defined the `<` and `==` operator for the class that you're using?

Comment: yaa i have defined== , < , !=  operators for the class that i am using


Yea... i am using poinetr element in the vectors for comparing.So thats the problem with std::sorting. So it is sorting with address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you've to use `typename` keyword here:

```
typename std::vector<T>::iterator it;
typename std::vector<T>::iterator it2;
```

without `typename` your code wouldn't even compile.

To compare the *values* pointed to by iterators, you've to do this:

```
if( *it == *it2)
```

---

You could write you compare function as:

```
//changed the name from CompareVectors() to equal()
template <typename T> 
bool equal(std::vector<T> v1, std::vector<T> v2)
{
  std::sort(v1.begin(),v1.end());
  std::sort(v2.begin(),v2.end());
  if ( v1.size() != v2.size() )
       return false;
  return std::equal(v1.begin(),v1.end(), v2.begin());
};
```

Comment: Instead of testing the size and then calling `std::equal` you can simply say `return v1 == v2;`

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Thats good. I didn't know that there exists `==` non-member function to test equality of two vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Should this line:

```
if(it == it2)
```

be

```
if (*it == *it2)
```

The first line is comparing pointers not the values.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues here. First, you say that `std::sort()` doesn't work. Have you overloaded the `operator<` for your class?

Also, you need to compare what the iterators are *pointing* to:

```
*it == *it2
```

Further, you need to iterate through both arrays at the same time (just one loop):

```
for (it = vector1.begin(), it2 = vector2.begin();
     it != vector1.end(), it2 != vector2.end();
     it++, it2++) {
  ...
}
```

Though really, you should just use `std::equal()` by overloading the `operator==`.

And from an efficiency standpoint, you should compare the `size()` values *before* you bother sorting the arrays.